# Is it possible to double viewport height in jquery function

Tags: jquery, viewport

I have a very basic jquery question. Is it possible to do some arithmetic operations on viewport variables? And if so how, I cant seem to get it.

```
 <script>
       var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
       var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

     if (scroll >= 2*viewportHeight ) {  //<-- would like to add a class when the user has scrolled past or at 2x their original viewport//
            $("#one").addClass("sele");
            $("#two").removeClass("sele");

      }
    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try running that code inside a `scroll` even handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
$(window).scroll(function(){
     if ($(window).scrollTop() >  2*viewportHeight ) {               
            $("#one").addClass("sele");
            $("#two").removeClass("sele");

      }
});
```

**Live [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69to13kt/)**

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to roll that script up into some sort of event. There is a scroll event in jquery, $(window).scroll(function(){your code}); should do the trick.

you also need to define what 'scroll' is since its not anything at the moment.